# changing float format to have both decimals and commas

Tags: python, string

For example, how would do you make `1003.2` format to `1,003.20`?

I know I can use `'%.2f' % 1003.2` to make it have two decimal places, but how do you also make the comma appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> '{:,.2f}'.format(1003.2)
'1,003.20'
```

The `','` format specification signals the use of a comma for a thousands separator.